# Display image in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Image url as database field and i want to display image with the url in table..

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
     <th>LastName</th>
     <th>EmailID</th>
     <th>Mobile</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Country</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var data in Model.alldata)
{
<tr>

    <td><img src= " @data.ImageUrl" /></td>
    <td>@data.FirstName</td>
    <td>@data.LastName</td>
    <td>@data.EmailID</td>
    <td>@data.Mobile</td>
    <td>@data.Address</td>
    <td>@data.Country</td>
</tr>
}
```

here what i should write for display image as i have url in database field and image is in Img folder.

Comment: is `@data.ImageUrl` giving you a valid path to an image ? Try without the space

Comment: You should include an empty `<th></th>` to match the image column (assuming you don't want it to have a header).

Answer (score 0):

sorry sorry i got it..

```
<img src="@Url.Action(data.ImgUrl)">
```